# Read YAML file as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have a YAML file that goes as (just an example):

```
a:
    b: 1    
a:
    b: 2    
    c: 1
a:
    b: 3
```

I want to read this file, and do some stuff with `b`s and `c`s. The problem is that I can't read this file as a dictionary using `yaml.load()`, since it will only give me `{'a':{'b': 3 }}`. Instead, I want to read it as a list of dictionaries, i.e, I want the output to be something like:

```
[
    {'a':{'b': 1 }},
    {'a':{'b': 2, 'c': 1 }},
    {'a':{'b': 3 }}
]
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks...

Comment: Just put a `-` before each of the `a:` in the yaml file. Like this: `- a:`

Comment: As the answers point out, your YAML file is simply invalid. What is really important here is that generating a YAML file by hand or with "a simple tool that just prints the keys in order", "prepends with `-`" or whatever, is wrong. YAML is a complicated standard with many exceptions, the only valid way of generating YAML is using a YAML-generating library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest YAML specification (1.2, from 2009) is quite explicit that keys in a mapping cannot be duplicated:

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

As presented your file is not a valid YAML file and loading it should give you
a `DuplicateKeyError`.

Since you know what you want to get, the easiest way to see what YAML would load like that is to dump the data structure:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = [
    {'a':{'b': 1 }},
    {'a':{'b': 2, 'c': 1 }},
    {'a':{'b': 3 }}
]
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- a:
    b: 1
- a:
    b: 2
    c: 1
- a:
    b: 3
```

Comment: Wow! I knew from the comments that `- a` can be used in yaml file, but didn't know I can even get that like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the snippet below as YAML

```
a:
    - b: 1    
    - b: 2    
      c: 1
    - b: 3
```

And get this dict in python (no need to duplicate 'a')

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": 1
    }, 
    {
      "c": 1, 
      "b": 2
    }, 
    {
      "b": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's the user who will be duplicating `a`, and not me. But I liked your approach in this answer anyway. Thanks!